# How to use AWS SKD for .Net in VBA?

Tags: vba, amazon-web-services, sdk, nlp

I am trying to add AWS Comprehend NLP to my VBA project but there seems to be no support for VBA. AWS does provide a .NET SDK. What is the best way to make classes from this SDK available to my VBA code?

Here is a mockup of a VBA module to pass a string of text to Comprehend and get the sentiment analysis back. Obviously, it doesn't actually work.

This module could be very helpful to anyone working in VBA and wanting to add AWS services to their toolkit. Can you help?

```
Function putAWSComprehendJSON(link As String, apiKey As String, apiSecret As String, text2comp As String) As Dictionary
'link=https://Comprehend.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Dim endpoint as String
endpoint = "/api/endpointX"
'VBA-JSON module installed from github to handle Json packing and unpacking
Dim jsonResponse As Dictionary
Dim jsonRequest As Dictionary
Set jsonRequest = New Dictionary
jsonRequest.Add key:="action", item:="detect-sentiment"
jsonRequest.Add key:="content", item:=text2comp
jsonRequest.Add key:="content-usage-code", item:="en"
jsonRequest.Add key:="region", item:="usl-east-1"
jsonRequestBody = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonRequest)
Dim web As msxml2.XMLHTTP60
Set web = New msxml2.XMLHTTP60
With web
    .Open "POST", link & endpoint, False, apiKey, apiSecret
    .setRequestHeader "cache-control", "private"
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64
    .send jsonRequestBody
End With
While .readyState 4
DoEvents
Wend
Set putAWSComprehendJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(web.responseText)
End Function
```

Comment: VBA doesn't specifically/officially have support in many platforms, so this isn't a surprise, but it looks like you're just trying to POST to a url and parse a JSON response, is that correct?  If so, it doesn't need to be language-specific... JSON is just a text file that can be handled with standard string functions or RegEx.

Comment: Things like [Amazon S3 Examples for VBScript](https://www.example-code.com/vbscript/s3.asp) suggest that you could use the AWS SDK.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think. Can you help me understand how to access those classes in VBA? It's not just a matter of installing something from the reference library or downloading a GitHub module, unless, of course, you know of one.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein these are nice examples but they require a license to use Chilkat for the http request. I could easily adapt the vbscript but I'm having a little difficulty understanding how to pass the authentication parameters.